# How to get a mutable slice from a shared slice? Rc<[T]>

Tags: rust, slice

I am trying to implement multiple "slices" over a shared array of objects. My solution is to morally  make a

```
struct MySlice<T>{ shared_data: Rc<[T]> , beg: usize, len: usize }
```

I want to be able to implement both

- `impl From<Vec<T>> for MySlice<T> { /* ?? */ }`
- and `fn get_mut_slice(&mut MySlice<T>) -> &mut [T]` which returns the entire underlying slice.

With the above implementation I can get the former but not the latter. I tried modifying the type into

```
struct MySlice1<T>{ shared_data: Rc<RefCell<[T]>> , beg: usize, len: usize }
```

But I couldn't get it to work. Is there an idiomatic way to get both?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the latter with `RefCell`? [I couldn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=848bea893150af8d6378c9f485ac5081).

Comment: You are right, it was a stupid mistake. Actually I cant get the latter either (I edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

The first can be done by storing a `Rc<RefCell<Vec<T>>>`. I don't think this can be done with a slice, unfortunately.

The second cannot exist as-is. If you have shared ownership, and you want to get a mutable reference, you have to make sure nobody else will use the value as long as the mutable reference is active. This can only be done with a guard. You can change its signature to:

```rust
pub fn get_mut_slice(&mut MySlice<T>) -> RefMut<'_, [T]>
```

Then:

```rust
pub fn get_mut_slice(&mut self) -> RefMut<'_, [T]> {
    RefMut::map(self.shared_data.borrow_mut(), |s| {
        &mut s[self.beg..][..self.len]
    })
}
```